# Error creating an array of SCNNodes

Tags: arrays, swift

Trying to create an array of nodes for a set of images and failing miserably, not too experienced with working with scene kit.

Trying to get

```
    func addNumbers() {

    let v1 = drand48()
    let v2 = drand48()
    let v3 = drand48()

    var nodeArray : [SCNScene] = []
    var i = 0
    while(i < 10) {
        nodeArray[i] = SCNScene(named: "\(i).dae")!
        self.nodes[i] = nodeArray[i].rootNode.childNode(withName: "\(i)", recursively: false)!
        nodes[i].position = SCNVector3(v1, v2, v3)
        nodes[i].physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.static()
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodes[i])
        i += 1
    }
```

to work and failing every time due to "Fatal error: Index out of range" when trying to run

```
    nodeArray[i] = SCNScene(named: "\(i).dae")!
```

can anyone help?

Using XCode 9 and swift 4.1

Comment: Not related but please replace `while(i < 10) {` with `for i in 0..<10 {` and delete the lines `var i = 0` and `i += 1`

Comment: done, only did it like that because everytime i tried to use a for loop (the wrong way apparently) it was telling me what i was doing was removed after swift 3, ty for the help tho

Comment: `++` and `--` were removed, not the `for` loop itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a SceneKit question, but a misunderstanding of how to add elements to an empty mutable `Array`. Please have a look at the [Collection Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) guide.

You'll want to use `nodeArray.append(…)` instead of `nodeArray[i] = …`.